# Ghidra python - retrieve the name of the called method

Tags: ghidra, static-analysis, python

I am using Ghidra to build the function call graph of a method in java and therefore I am analyzing the bytecode of java and when I read an "invoke" instruction I have to go back to the name of the called method.

Do you know how to do this through a python script?